# Where can I get the "Secret" Unikong music?

Tags: unikong

I'm no stranger to secret codes.
You know the inputs and so do I.
A full download would be all right.
You wouldn't get this from any other site.
I just wanna find out how to get it.
Gotta make it my ringtone.

How do I get this song?
How do I pull it down?
How do I browse around and save you?
How do I make you mine?
How do I build this shrine?
How do I find the file and save you?

> Can I download the rick astley background music that plays after you input the Konami Code?

Comment: It is ending and starting sound combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277763/252574:

> As I mentioned in the comments, we didn't make this particular rendition of the timeless classic.
>
> The credit (also listed in the game itself) belongs to [Toast024](http://youtube.com/user/Toast024) on Youtube. We've edited it to create a version better suited to looping indefinitely, but here's the tune itself:
>
> .

Also, from a comment on that question, the game itself uses [this trimmed version](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/unikong/game-over-music.mp3)